# Migrate Kubernetes from on-premise to AWS EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

In my organization, I need to migrate the Kubernetes cluster from on-premise to AWS EKS. Can someone please tell me how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways and things to consider however you have to ask a board questions so will write an answer accordingly.

You can use the tool **velero** to migrate the internal components of the Kubernetes cluster.

Velero : https://velero.io/

While other all things you have to consider of migrating Databases using DMS, Storage option like PV and PVC or NFS that used with on-prem K8s.

Answer (score 0):

That’s quite broad question. It can have many approaches & flavours based on organisation needs.

One of the approach is to

1. Standup the eks cluster based on the needs of the workload you are going to run. Note that EKS can also be deployed in to flavours as managed nodes & other as serverless.
2. Setup the authentication & authorisation model for users & admins for eks cluster.
3. Defined strategy to how & when to migrate load to EKS.

Very important note is you must gather all NFRs for your cluster & create a plan to how to full fill those requirements before you start on the above.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But what is NFR's?

Comment: NFR are non functional requirements - like security , performance , monitoring , alerting , capacity etc which are not required for applicational functionality but are required to make sure that applications remain stable & resilient .